# Creating a word creator java standalone application

Tags: java, swing, ms-word, treeview

I want to create a simple java standalone application where in I could create a MS Word file by selecting different texts from notepad and images from local folder to which my application would be directed.

Like I want to have a root folder in which I will have multiple folders which would be shown like a tree structure and when I open each folder I could select the required texts or images and select them to create my Word file.

Please suggest me what should I use to do this? JAVA Swing GUI is a good suggestion as far as I know.Any other ideas.. Also which JAR i should use for Creating Word files..
Thanx in advance....

Comment: Sorry to post such a broad scope question in the forum..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a MS Word file you can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

For the interface Swing is a good choice.